# Puppet master does not receive cert request from client

Tags: certificate, puppet

Netstat shows the puppet master listening on port 8140

The client is configured as shown here:

```
# /etc/hosts file:
192.xx.xx.xx   bt-ppt-client
192.yy.yy.yy   bt-ppt-master

# /etc/puppet/puppet.conf (agent section)
server = puppet
report = true
pluginsync = true

# set puppet agent to run on boot:
chkconfig puppet on
puppet agent --daemonize
```

This was all done as root user.  I run 'puppet cert list' on the puppet master and do not find any cert requests.

Comment: What happens when you run `puppet agent` on the client ? Is there any error ? Can you post the output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more information, the answer can't be conclusive. I believe the problem is with the line :

```
server = puppet
```

How does the client know what `puppet` is  ? Your `/etc/hosts` shows master `hostname` as `bt-ppt-master`. Either change the hostname of puppet-master machine to `puppet.org.name` or alias `bt-puppet-master` as puppet. THat line in `/etc/hosts` may look like this

```
192.yy.yy.yy   bt-ppt-master puppet
```